# Zechuyos for one to get better

Tags: reward-punishment, choleh-sick

Someone is sick and needs a refuah shleima. Besides *tefillah,* what is the most effective zechus for him to get better:

1)*Torah*,

2) *Chesed* or

3) *Shemiras HaLoshon*?

Comment: What defines best? Most likely to work? I doubt you can make that evaluation. תשובה, תפילה, צדקה - you got all of the points there.

Comment: How do you know it's one of those three? Maybe it's giving Zeroa Lechayayim and Keiva to a Kohein? Maybe it's just keeping halacha always (something most of us fail it in different ways)?

Comment: @Double AA Yes! [Rav Leuchter at 11:30 mins](http://ravleuchter.com/?p=3802) speaks about a response to tragedy R”L. He says that there is a danger in assuming the reason that HKB”H brought a bad situation. Everything that comes from HKB”H, he says at 22:30 mins, comes with a planned approach which speaks to those affected. The response should be personal and not generic.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok are you allowed to post his shiurim? I know he is makpid in general

Comment: @Mefaresh There is a publicly available website: http://ravleuchter.com .

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok just was checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choices you bring are not the one's mentioned in Halacha. Here's an overview of what the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch brings:

1. **Teshuva** & **Prayer**

See [סימן קכז - הלכות תענית יחיד](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0126_L2) in the Kitzur:

> כְּשֵׁם שֶׁמִּצְוָה עַל הַצִּבּוּר לְהִתְעַנּוֹת וּלְהִתְפַּלֵּל עַל כָּל צָרָה שֶׁלֹּא תָבוֹא, כָּךְ מִצְוָה עַל כָּל יָחִיד שֶׁאִם בָּאָה עָלָיו חַס וְשָׁלוֹם אֵיזוֹ צָרָה, כְּגוֹן **שֶׁהָיָה לוֹ חוֹלֶה בְּתוֹךְ בֵּיתוֹ**, אוֹ שֶׁהוּא תּוֹעֶה בַּדֶּרֶךְ, אוֹ חָבוּשׁ בְּבֵית הָאֲסוּרִים עַל יְדֵי עֲלִילָה, **מִצְוָה עָלָיו שֶׁיִּתְעַנֶּה וְיִתְפַּלֵּל אֶל ה' וִיבַקֵּשׁ רַחֲמִים מֵאִתּוֹ** יִתְבָּרַךְ שְׁמוֹ שֶׁיּוֹשִׁיעַ לוֹ. וְדָבָר זֶה מִדַּרְכֵי **תְשׁוּבָה** הוּא, שֶׁלֹּא יֹאמַר הָאָדָם, חַס וְשָׁלוֹם מִקְרֶה הִיא הַצָּרָה, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר וַהֲלַכְתֶם עִמִּי בְּקֶרִי, וְהָלַכְתִּי גַם אֲנִי עִמָּכֶם בַּחֲמַת קֶרִי. פֵּרושׁ, כְּשֶׁאָבִיא עֲלֵיכֶם צָרָה כְּדֵי שֶׁתָּשׁוּבוּ, אִם תֹּאמְרוּ שֶׁהוּא קֶרִי, אוֹסִיף עֲלֵיכֶם חֲמַת אוֹתוֹ קֶרִי, אֲבָל צָרִיךְ הָאָדָם לָדַעַת כִּי בַּחֲטָאָיו הֵבִיא עָלָיו הָאֱלֹהִים אֶת כָּל הָרָעָה הַזֹּאת, וִיפַשְׁפֵּשׁ בְּמַעֲשָׂיו, וְיָשׁוּב אֶל ה' וִירַחֲמֵהוּ‏

2. **Charity** & **Getting great people to pray for them**

See [סימן קצב - דין החולה והרופא](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0191_L2) in the Kitzur:

> דָּרַשׁ רַבִּי פִּינְחָס בַּר חָמָא, כָּל מִי שֶׁיֵשׁ לוֹ חוֹלֶה בְּתוֹךְ בֵּיתוֹ, **יֵלֵךְ אֵצֶל חָכָם וִיבַקֵּשׁ עָלָיו רַחֲמִים**, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר, חֲמַת מֶלֶךְ מַלְאֲכֵי מָוֶת, וְאִישׁ חָכָם יְכַפְּרֶנָּה. וְנוֹהֲגִין **לָתֵת צְדָקָה לַעֲנִיִים בַּעֲדוֹ**, כִּי תְּשׁוּבָה וּתְפִלָּה וּצְדָקָה, מַעֲבִירִין אֶת רֹעַ הַגְּזֵרָה.‏